# Adding a simple payment method in Ubercart

Tags: ubercart

I am on Drupal 7. In Ubercart, I need to add a very simple payment method. It is more of a bypass than a payment method. I will be implementing cash payment method. Basically, the transaction will be completed offline, in the real world, and I just need the system to store the information that payment has been processed in cash.

The system isn`t open for external use, so only the employees will be using it and they have authority to pick "cash"as a payment method. Hitting the "next" button on the cart checkout page with the "cash" payment method will record the transaction. It is almost like a "bypass" method, but of course I need the system to register payment has been done in cash. Since later I will need to run reports, I need to have the information on the payment method associated with each order. But that is pretty much it.

I am searching all around for something as simple as that, but can`t find. Do you know of any modules that will perform something more or less like this that could serve as a starting point so that I can create my own? Or even you might know of a module that does exactly that.

If such a module doesn`t exist, what do I need to implement to get a simple payment method on the road? I need to add a payment method to the list and I need that information to be recorded and associated with my order. Any help or hints will be highly appreciated, thank you.